Does an adult child living at home still gets the standard tax credit?
If someone, age 19, lives with their parents, works part time, do they still qualify for the standard tax credit? The person earned $2584 last year. The tax preparer says she owes $390 in taxes.

What country are you at? What's "standard tax credit"? Are you talking about the US standard deduction?

Have you looked at the forms the tax preparer drew up? Do they make sense?

Yes, I am talking about the US standard deduction. Sorry, I used the wrong term.

If they are filing their own taxes, rather than being listed as someone else's dependent, then they fill out the standard forms ... And yes that means standard deduction applies unless they prefer to itemize. 390/2500ish is roughly a 15% income tax rate; I would have expected 10% for that amount but we'd need to see the rest of the numbers to offer anything but guesses.

Thank you for your response. That's what I was thinking too.
